# How to copy elements from array one to array two using recursion?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am trying to copy the elements from src (Array 1) to tgt (Array 2) using recursion. Len is an integer value that determines how many of the elements should be transferred. For example, if len is 4, I take 4 elements out of Array 1 and transfer them to Array 2.

Start is the starting location of array src, and this value is transferred to location start2 of array tgt. Then I recursively copy the remaining len-1 elements. Returning out of bound exception.

```
public void arraycopy(double[] src, int start, double[] tgt, int start2, int len){
    if(len < 1) return;
    if(len > src.length) return;

    tgt[start2] = src[start];
    arraycopy(src, start + 1, tgt, start2 + 1, len);

}
```

Comment: Can you expand on "doing nothing"?

Comment: Aside from being one of the most inefficient ways to go about doing this, have you considered the case where the start position is larger than the copy length? Consider a 100 element array, starting from element 50 copying 10 elements will result in the method "doing nothing" since `start` is already greater or equal to `len` to start with.

Comment: @BCronyn        what are you trying to achieve from SO really? The functionality (recursive function) or the full-proof method (with validation and stuff)..

Answer (score 5):

First, you are not treating `len` as the number of characters to copy.  You are treating it as an ending index with this condition:

```
if(start < len){
```

You can change it to

```
if (len > 0)
```

but at that point, `len` is already greater than `0` because the base case `len < 1` is already past.  You can remove that `if` condition entirely.

Second, pass `len - 1` in the recursive call:

```
arraycopy(src, start+1, tgt, start2+1, len - 1);
```

Third, if `len` is greater than the source array's `length`:

```
if (len > src.length) return;
```

then all you do is `return`, leading to an uncopied array and a confused caller.  I would remove this line entirely.  You can let Java throw the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, passing it to the caller.  If you must perform the bounds check, then test it yourself properly, for both the source and destination arrays.

```
if (start < 0 || start + len > src.length || start2 < 0 || start2 + len > tgt.length) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Out of bounds");
}
```

Comment: Perfect – I got it working thanks to your comment. I had clearly misunderstood the len input. ...and the len-1 argument seemed like the most crucial piece in the puzzle that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass two position integer. One is enough.
Check out the code. And also pass the actual length not (len-1)

```
public static void arraycopy(double[] src, int start, double[] tgt, int len){
   if (len != src.length) return;
   if (start<len){
         tgt[start] = src[start];
         arraycopy(src, start+1, tgt, len);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that my first attempt had some definite confusion mixed in. Thanks to rgettman^ I was able to make my code more concise and have it pass all my tests!

```
public void arraycopy(double[] src, int start, double[] tgt, int start2, int len){
   if (start < 0 || start + len > src.length || start2 < 0 || start2 + len > tgt.length) return;
   if (len > 0){
     tgt[start2] = src[start];
     arraycopy(src, start+1, tgt, start2+1, len-1);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class RecursiveArrayCopyAlgorithm {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String str = "ABCD";

    char[] chars =  str.toCharArray();

    char[] charElements = new char[chars.length];

    int charLen = chars.length-1;

    int charInitialIndex = 0;

    RecursiveArrayCopyAlgorithm testSearch = new RecursiveArrayCopyAlgorithm();

    char[] charObjs = testSearch.callLinear(charLen, charInitialIndex, chars, charElements);

    for (int i = 0; i < charObjs.length; i++) {         
        System.out.println(charObjs[i]);
    }
}

private char[] callLinear(int charLen, int index,char[] ch, char[] charElements) {
    int index1 = charLen;
    if(index1 < 0) {
        return charElements;
    }

    if(index1 >= 0) {
        charElements[index] = ch[index1];
    }

    return callLinear(charLen-1, index+1, ch, charElements);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you also explain your answer? Code without any explanation is not consider a proper SO answer (from review).